# Header image can't fit correctly (DrawerLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I need help. I've been trying to manipulate this but seems like I can't get this done. I'm trying to fit the image on drawer layout.
I'm invoking the header image layout (*header.xml*) as :

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/containerView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"/>

      <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         ....
         app:headerLayout="@layout/header" <!--THIS IS THE HEADER-->
        ...
   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For this (*header.xm*l) configuration :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/background"
      android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Twitter : @Someone important"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/twitter"
           android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
           />
   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text=" e-mail : someoneimportant@earth"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

I got

[image]

and tried to reduce the image layout height :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="140dp"
      android:src="@drawable/background"
      android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Twitter : @Someone important"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/twitter"
           android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
           />
   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text=" e-mail : someoneimportant@earth"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

I got the image cut off.

[image]

Comment: try adding `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to the header's XML

Comment: what style do u use for your activity?

Comment: it seems navview stands behind actionbar

Comment: hi mastrgamr, on which part? sorry I've been a bit dizzy thingking .., actually I'm trying to code it without getting depth into layout concept because of time line.

Comment: hi mastrgamr, I've add it the image scaled a bit little but still cut off , on the upper part of the image

Answer (score 1):

your image is not able to fit the screen because of the image size so you can set the scale type as fitxy in this way it will fill the left space and strech the image

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hi, I have just added the line but the image still got cropt off

Comment: it fit the screen?

Comment: what size of image you are using

Comment: it gets fits but the upper part of image still cut off. The original Image size is bigger , I just copied all your answer but still.

Comment: try to add this android:layout_marginTop="2dp"

Comment: the image size 399 x 335

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117007/discussion-between-neelay-srivastava-and-hey-men-whatsup).

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup are you still working in the project??

Comment: yeah, but I leaved it just like that coz I don't know how to get it right. Haha

Comment: I am try to change the width of the image as i tried the same way and i am getting the output

Comment: Well.... thanks for trying help to me at the time , I appreciate it :), _+1 for you